# How do I use htaccess to redirect files to another directory when they begin with a certain prefix?

Tags: .htaccess

I have created a new image gallery for my client's website to replace an existing gallery. In both galleries, all images are the same and share the same filenames.

The image files for the NEW gallery are stored in the directory /files/gallery. The image files for the OLD gallery are stored in the directory /files.

I want to delete the gallery images from /files, but redirect them to the /files/gallery directory where they can now be found.

Because the /files directory contains more than gallery images, I need an htaccess rule that will target only filenames beginning with the word 'gallery'.

I have spent hours searching for an answer, and have attempted to stitch together a solution using code from answers to similar problems, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what you tried already, here is a simple redirect with pattern matching:

```htaccess
RewriteRule /files/(gallery[^/]+)$ /files/gallery/$1 [L,R=301]
```

With this, `/files/gallery-pic01.png` will be redirected to `/files/gallery/gallery-pic01.png`.

If you need to get rid of the *gallery* prefix, just move the parenthesis of the capturing group:

```htaccess
RewriteRule /files/gallery([^/]+)$ /files/gallery/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In the regex, note the `[^/]` which means "*any character which is NOT a slash*". This will avoid redirects when someone requests `/files/gallery/new_picture.png`.

Comment: Redirect directive does not support a regex based pattern.

Comment: @starkeen mixed it up, sorry. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Derlin.
Unfortunately the rule did not work. RewriteEngine is on, and according to my host, mod_rewrite is enabled on the server. I don't know what else it could be.